# Port forwarding from router for external remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, portforwarding

I am trying to set up the server at an organization I work with to allow me to access a remote desktop from home (or where ever).  I tried to set up a port on the internet Gateway to forward to the local IP address of the server.  However, there is a router between the Gateway and the server, so the Gateway only recognized the IP address of the router.  How can I set it up to remote into the server?

And yes, I am using the ip address from the ISP--not the local ip address of the gateway, router, or server--from external locations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup port forwarding on both - router and gateway.